# Splitting a string and building another string in java

Tags: java, split, stringbuilder

I need a function which returns `"A[1]"` which takes input `"A1"`. Can anyone please be of help?

```
public static String build(String source) {
    int i, len = source.length();
    StringBuffer sample = new StringBuffer(len);

    for (i = 0; i<len; i++)
        sample.append("["+source.charAt(i)+"]");

    return sample.toString();
}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. Is the length always 2? Is the number always one digit?

Comment: Sorry! length can be max 3 and digits will be 2(alphabets only 1) Thank you.

Comment: we are here to _help_, not to do the whole thing for you. at least show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Please edit the question to include all the information you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String doProcess(String str) {
    return str.substring(0,1)+"["+str.substring(1)+"]";
}
```